# Kotlin – String formatting

Tags: string-formatting, kotlin

Kotlin has an excellent feature called string templates.

```
val i = 10 
val s = "i = $i" // evaluates to "i = 10"
```

But is it possible to have any formatting in the templates? For example, I would like to format Double in string templates in kotlin, at least to set a number of digits after a decimal separator:

```
val pi = 3.14159265358979323
val s = "pi = $pi??" // How to make it "pi = 3.14"?
```

Comment: Is there any multiplatform solution to this?

Comment: At least you can use `.format` as a workaround. Unfortunately in KMM, `String.format` is still not available, at least til' 2022. It's not in `stdlib.text` or `kotlinx`. String template is cool but C style formatting is fundamental, I assume the complexity is perhaps based on variant variable list, but it's still quite disappointing.

Comment: @superarts.org YEP! Ran into this exact thing just now! String.format isn't there in KMM! Amazing how much of Kotlin works in KMM so far, and it's mostly been an exercise of de-java-ifying it all, but things like String.format not there, the helL
Also, Array.plus(element) isn't there, and Array.plus(Array) is there - inconsistent (oversight probably).

Answer (score 372, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no built-in support for formatting in string templates yet, as a workaround, you can use something like:

```
"pi = ${pi.format(2)}"
```

the `.format(n)` function you'd need to define yourself as

```
fun Double.format(digits: Int) = "%.${digits}f".format(this)
```

This will work only in Kotlin/JVM.

There's clearly a piece of functionality here that is missing from Kotlin at the moment, we'll fix it.

Comment: @AndreyBreslav How does String interpolation format float/double values? Is the decimal point locale dependent or always a dot?

Comment: It calls `Double.toString()`

Comment: In Kotlin you can do `"%.${digits}f".format(pi)` to be more concise. The literal string is evaluated to a String class.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-4859

Comment: It converts 1.32646163E14 to 132646163000000.0 !!!

Comment: @HosseinKurd of course it does, if you need the exponent, just use the plain `"$number"` or `number.toString()`

Comment: The problem I see with this method, is that the dot in Double value, is converting to comma, when we need the return type of String

Comment: Well hello from 2023... and... still...not available I think.

Answer (score 197):

As a workaround, [There is a Kotlin stdlib function](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/65244b4bea81f737466618927d4f3afe339cad0d/libraries/stdlib/jvm/test/text/StringJVMTest.kt#L37) that can be used in a nice way and fully compatible with Java's String format (it's only a wrapper around Java's `String.format()`)

See Kotlin's [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/format.html)

Your code would be:

```
val pi = 3.14159265358979323
val s = "pi = %.2f".format(pi)
```

Comment: I'm guessing he meant this documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.util.Locale-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-

Comment: @Rob See also [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086291/format-in-kotlin-string-templates#comment79967924_33492636) on the documentation

Answer (score 46):

Kotlin's String class has a [format](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/format.html) function now, which internally uses Java's `String.format` method:

```
/**
 * Uses this string as a format string and returns a string obtained by substituting the specified arguments,
 * using the default locale.
 */
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun String.Companion.format(format: String, vararg args: Any?): String = java.lang.String.format(format, *args)
```

Usage

```
val pi = 3.14159265358979323
val formatted = String.format("%.2f", pi) ;
println(formatted)
>>3.14
```

Comment: String.Companion.format is not found now in Kotlin v1.2.21. What is the alternative?.

Answer (score 43):

It's simple, use:

```
val str: String = "%.2f".format(3.14159)
```

Answer (score 8):

Since `String.format` is only an extension function (see [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/text/StringsJVM.kt#L100)) which internally calls `java.lang.String.format` you could write your own extension function using Java's [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) if you need more flexibility:

```
fun Double.format(fracDigits: Int): String {
    val df = DecimalFormat()
    df.setMaximumFractionDigits(fracDigits)
    return df.format(this)
}

println(3.14159.format(2)) // 3.14
```

Answer (score 4):

A couple of examples:

```
infix fun Double.f(fmt: String) = "%$fmt".format(this)
infix fun Double.f(fmt: Float) = "%${if (fmt < 1) fmt + 1 else fmt}f".format(this)

val pi = 3.14159265358979323

println("""pi = ${pi f ".2f"}""")
println("pi = ${pi f .2f}")
```

Answer (score 3):

**Kotlin 1.9.10**

String's `format` method takes in a formatter-string and any number of args in nullable Any type.

```
fun String.Companion.format(format: String, vararg args: Any?) : String
```

Real code may look like this:

```
fun main() {
    val pi: Double = 3.141592653589
    val gravity: Double = 9.80665
    var str = String.Companion.format("PI = %.2f %n G = %.2f", pi, gravity)

    println(str)
}
```

Where `%f` is Float in Decimal Format and `%n` is a line separator.

Results are:

```
//   PI = 3.14 
//    G = 9.81
```

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround simple solution for multiplatform you can use:

```
import kotlin.math.abs
import kotlin.math.pow

fun Number.simpleFormat(numberDigitsAfterSeparator: Int = 0, decimalSeparator: Char = ','): String {
    if(numberDigitsAfterSeparator < 0)
        throw IllegalArgumentException("numberDigitsAfterSeparator should be >= 0 but is $numberDigitsAfterSeparator")

    val prefix = this.toInt()
    if(numberDigitsAfterSeparator == 0)return "$prefix"

    val sign = if(this.toDouble() >= 0.0) "" else "-"

    val afterSeparatorPart = abs(this.toDouble() - prefix)
    val suffixInt = (10.0.pow(numberDigitsAfterSeparator) * afterSeparatorPart).toInt()
    val suffix = if(afterSeparatorPart >= 1.0) "$suffixInt" else addNullsBefore(suffixInt, numberDigitsAfterSeparator)
    return "$sign${abs(prefix)}$decimalSeparator$suffix"
}

fun addNullsBefore(suffixInt: Int, numberDigitsAfterSeparator: Int): String {
    var s = "$suffixInt"
    val len = s.length
    repeat(numberDigitsAfterSeparator - len) { _ -> s = "0$s" }
    return s
}
```

Test:

```
fun main() {


    println((-0.00001).simpleFormat(5))
    println(3.1415927.simpleFormat(2))
    println(3.99.simpleFormat(2))
    println((-3.99).simpleFormat(2))

    println(3.1415927.simpleFormat())
    println(3.99.simpleFormat())
    println((-3.99).simpleFormat())

    println((-3.99).simpleFormat(-1))
}
```

wiht output:

```
-0,00001
3,14
3,99
-3,99
3
3
-3
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: numberDigitsAfterSeparator should be >= 0 but is -1..
```

Comment: Thank you bro, you saved my hour of self implementation

Comment: Bro, you have a problem in your solution: floating-point arithmetic. Your does not work with 12.1 or 12.42 and so on. You can convert to BigDecimal to avoid this problem. I suggest to update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It has string formatting Example in Kotlin for Android TextView:

```
val format = String.format("<font color=#3177a3> test1: <b>%s</b><br> test2: <b>%s</b><br> test3: <b>%s</b></font>", "value1", "value2", "value3")
textView.text = format
```

Answer (score -7):

It has string formatting
Example:

```
fun printSum(a: Int, b: Int): Unit {
    println("sum of $a and $b is ${a + b}")
}
```