# String interpolation for double number in Kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin, string-interpolation

How to use string interpolation for a double with 2 numbers after the period in Kotlin?

For example

```
val d = 3.54213
println("d = $d")
```

will get `d = 3.54213`.

I want to get `d = 3.54`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
   // string interpolation
    val d = 3.54213
    println("d = %.2f".format(d))
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086291/format-in-kotlin-string-templates) too has the same answer but it says

> There's clearly a piece of functionality here that is missing from
>   Kotlin at the moment, we'll fix it.

Soon, you would see this on Kotlin.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can try it like this

```
val df = DecimalFormat("#.00")
val d1 = 3.54213
df.format(d1)
```