# Decimal format in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to use a method or something else rather “%.6f”.format(value) in order to achieve the same thing?
this is my code :

```
println("%.6f".format(value))
```

I'll want to make it more dynamic and readable

Comment: I would say this is already readable. What do you mean by dynamic?

Comment: Maybe [Andrey Breslavs answer to 'Format in kotlin string template'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23088000/6202869) is something for you... basically move that formatting into its own extension function...

Answer (score 5):

You can make it an **Extension Function** for your project, which is a very powerful feature of Kotlin, the function is like this:

```
fun Double.roundDecimal(digit: Int) = "%.${digit}f".format(this)
```

Just put it in a Kotlin file **But Outside The Class**, then you can access it everywhere in your project:

```
fun main() {
    val number = 0.49555

    println(number.roundDecimal(2))
    println(number.roundDecimal(3))
}
```

Output:

```
0.50
0.496
```

Answer (score 3):

You can always use

```
String.format("%.6f", value)
```

But you can extract the format in a variable

```
val FORMAT_FLOAT = "%.6f"
println(String.format(FORMAT_FLOAT, value))
```

It depends on your preferences. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `DecimalFormat` class to round a given number. [More info](https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/examples/round-number-decimal)

i.e.

```
val num = 1.345672
    val df = DecimalFormat("#.######")
    df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.CEILING

    println(df.format(num))
```